# make external links dynamic in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to make external (custom) links in the navigation menu of WordPress dynamic?

With this I mean that links to external websites added to the menu using custom links will keep working if the URL or subdomain of the external website changes. For example, a WordPress website which is at www.myblog.com will have a custom link in the nav menu that goes to www.externalsite.com/link1

Normally you would add the entire URL of course. But is there a way to add only /link1 and WordPress will add everything infront? That way if www.externalsite.com changes to dev.externalsite.com for example, the links don't need to be changed manually?

I'm thinking there's probably a way to do it using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`
But I don't know where to do it (maybe header or functions files) and how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible. If the link to the external site changes, you have to update it manually to the new URL.

You can't update it automatically unless you let the external website tell you where it's moved to. But that means creating a API and allowing external sites to remotely updates it's location on your site. Not ideal as it could allow someone to add malicious URLs to your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following in the 'functions.php' of your child theme.
This sets the external website for all dynamic links that exist in your menu. You can replace the URL in the code in case it changes.

```
function custom_url_nav_menu_link_attributes( $atts ) {
    // Set URL 
    $url = 'http://example.com';

    // Prepend URL on all dynamic links
    if ( strpos( $atts['href'], 'http' ) === false ) {
        $atts['href'] = $url . $atts['href'];
    }

    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'custom_url_nav_menu_link_attributes' );
```

Comment: But in this case it still has to be changed manually. I was looking for a way that the end user of the blog doesn't have to care about it.

Comment: If the external website changes from www.example.com to dev.example.com then there is no way for your website to be aware of that. The link will be broken unless the external website redirects you to the correct URL.